# validating hyphen in javascript to only have one

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to validate my text field in javascript so that it would only have one hyphen.

I managed to make it so they cannot be side by side but that's inefficient since the user can still input the hyphen else where.

What I tried to do is this:

```
if (surname.indexOf("-") > 1)

{

 err += "You cannot use more than one hyphen (-) for Client Surname";

}
```

But that did not work. I also tried >=2 still no good.

What would you suggest looking into or trying?

Thanks.

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't give the number of instances of hyphen. It will give you the index of the hyphen in the string. So, `indexOf('-')` for the string `foo-bar` will return you 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((surname.length - surname.replace('-', '').length) >= 2) {
     err += "You cannot use more than one hyphen (-) for Client Surname";
}
```

Basically, take the length of the original string and compare it against the length of the string with all the hyphens removed. If the difference is 2 or more, there's more than 1 hypen.

Comment: You could also do `surname.replace(/[^-]/gi, '').length > 1`.

Comment: @jared: that'd work too, but regexes are pretty heavy guns for this sort of thing.

Comment: I think it's relative. This particular usage, with the limited amount of text and the single-fire nature, I don't think it's a big deal. Repeatedly, over thousands of line, I see your point.

Comment: I'm also wondering maybe about `&emdash;`s; is it possible for that to be copy/pasted into an input field?

Comment: I never knew about replace() method, this is awesome. Thank you for the explanation of it as well.

Comment: As discussed earlier it may be prudent to put this into a function if you plan on using this throughout your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .match() + regex to do this.

```
if(surname.match(/\-/g).length>1) err+='Too many hyphens!';
```

Comment: this is even more simple than the other regex answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Nah....here is a simple solution my friend:

```
var str="My-Name-Is-Jhon";
var count = str.match(/-/g);  
alert(count.length);
```

It will alert you 3.

Comment: You could just do `str.match(/-/g).length`, too.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thats for sure, thanks for the advice, Umeed, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

```
function tooManyHyphens(str){
  return str.split("-").length < 3;
}

var test1 = "Something-Something";
var test2 = "some-thing-some";
var test3 = "some";

console.log(tooManyHyphens(test1));
console.log(tooManyHyphens(test2));
console.log(tooManyHyphens(test3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p9rHe/1/

Comment: You don't need a function per se, `surname.split('-').length` would work just fine in the condition.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I would put it in a function in case you decided to allow more hyphens later.  Then you only have to change the function and the changes will replicate throughout the application.  Instead of changing every condition that checks the length of the array.  I'm big on OOP so it may just be my preference.

Comment: Either way, you don't need the `var tokens`, just return the length.

Comment: @JaredFarrish agreed that part could be condensed I will edit.

Comment: so wait, how come we didn't need var tokens? Is it because returning the length would provide the number of instances a hyphen would appear?

Comment: Storing the array return from split in a var was an intermediary step that was unnecessary.  The function still returns the array after the call to split and then the length property is retrieved from the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hyphens = 0;

for(var i = 0; i<surname.length; i++) {
    if(surname.charAt(i) == "-") hyphens++;
    if(hyphens > 1) {
        err += "You cannot use more than one hyphen (-) for Client Surname";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe i didnt think of this, excellent answer worked perfectly as well.